# Reactjs hover and display questions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a text based web game using react.

I have an ItemDisplay class which displays bunch of Item classes, each representing an item.

I used a lot of react-bootstrap to deal with modal and tooltip, but there are still some of the issues I haven't been able to solve.

Here's a screenshot of the ItemDisplay:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxJVY.jpg

`ItemDisplay` code

```
ItemDisplay
    class ItemDisplay extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: false
        }
    }
    render() {
        // items attributes are in object that looks like: {name: 'sword', desc: 'a stupid sword', atk: 8, dex: 1}, {name: 'shield', desc: 'a stupid shield', def: 1}];
        let items = Object.keys(this.props.items).map(item => <Item key={this.props.items[item].name} show={this.state.show} attri={this.props.items[item]}></Item>);


        return (
            <div className='item-list'>
                {items}
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default ItemDisplay;
```

and `Item` class

```
class Item extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            show: false
        };
        this.handleHoverOn = this.handleHoverOn.bind(this);
        this.handleHoverOff = this.handleHoverOff.bind(this);
    }

    handleHoverOn() {
        this.setState({show: true});
    }

    handleHoverOff() {
        this.setState({show: false});
    }

    toTitle = (word) => {
        return word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    }

    render() {
        let attributes = Object.keys(this.props.attri).map((key) => <p>{this.toTitle(key)}: {this.props.attri[key]}</p>)
        return (
            <div className='aux'>
                <OverlayTrigger key={this.props.attri.name} placement='top' className='item'
                                overlay={<Tooltip id={attributes.name}>{attributes}</Tooltip>}>
                    <p>{this.props.attri.name}</p>
                </OverlayTrigger>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Item;
```

Here are my problems:

1. As you can see from the screenshot, I cannot wrap `Sword of A Thousand Truths` within that box. I don't know if that's because I have a `div` wrapping the `OverlayTrigger`
2. As of now, hovering over the name of the items (only the words) will display the  attributes (atk ,def, etc.) in a `Tooltip`, but I want to be able to hover over the entire box instead of the words only to have the same effects. Is there a way to do it?

EDIT: Think I should add my css as well

ItemDisplay.css

```
.item-list {
    height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    broder: 1px solid black;
}
```

Item.css

```
.item {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.aux {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
```

}

```
.equip {
    border: 2px solid #267f0b;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```